# Yii - incorrect returned date range using CJuiDatePicker

Tags: php, yii, datepicker

Good Afternoon

I have a date picker in my view which selects the start_date and end_date.
my problem is that i cannot get the correct data with the selected date ranges.
I have a sample image below to show you what i mean.

Sample data:

[image]

if i select start_date (2015-10-01) then end_date (2015-10-29), 
it only returns this.
[image]

instead of this

[image]

I only get two dates which is the selected date from and selected date to.. the thing is it should return candidate 1, 2 and 3 because their dates is within the date range start_date (2015-10-01) until end_date (2015-10-29). what is wrong with my code. please help. can someone review my code.. maybe i miss something.

this is my view.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group"><label>Date From</label>
        <?php 
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'model' => $model,  
                'name' => 'start_date',
                'options'=>array(
                    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd', 
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    'placeholder'=>'From',
                    'value' => $search_date_start,
                ),
            ));  
        ?> 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group"><label>To</label>
        <div class="controls" style='margin-top: 5px;'>
            <?php 
            $end_date = date('m-d-Y');
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'model' => $model,  
                    'name' => 'end_date',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'placeholder'=>'To',
                        'value' => $search_date_end,
                    ),
                ));  
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name='search_btn' value="Search" class='btn btn-primary '>
        <input type="submit" name='reset_btn' value="Reset" class='btn btn-default '> 
    </div>
</form>
```

in my controller, i have added this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['search_btn'])) {

                if (isset($_POST['start_date']) && isset($_POST['end_date'])) {
                    $search_date_start = $_POST['start_date'];
                    $search_date_end = $_POST['end_date'];
                    Yii::app()->session['start_date_evaluation'] = $search_date_start;
                    Yii::app()->session['end_date_evaluation'] = $search_date_end;
                } 

                if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
                    $search = $_POST['search'];
                    Yii::app()->session['search_evaluation'] = $search;
                }
            }
```

in my model i have this code.

```
public function search($candidate_id, $search_date_start, $search_date_end, $search) {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched. 
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;        
        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('evaluation_form_id', $this->evaluation_form_id);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('evaluatee', $search);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('start_date', $search_date_start);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('end_date', $search_date_end);

        if ($candidate_id !== '') {
            $criteria->compare('employee_id', $candidate_id);
        } else {
            $criteria->compare('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
            $criteria->compare('evaluation_code', $this->evaluation_code);
            $criteria->compare('start_date', $this->start_date, true);
            $criteria->compare('end_date', $this->end_date, true);
            $criteria->compare('evaluatee', $this->evaluatee, true);
            $criteria->compare('date_created', $this->date_created, true);
            $criteria->compare('created_by', $this->created_by, true);
        }

      if ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== ''){
            $criteria->compare('start_date', $search_date_start, false, '>=');
            $criteria->compare('end_date', $search_date_end, false, '<=');
        } 

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));

    }
```

Comment: This is very unclear.  Rather than blacking out the candidate names, substitute fake names and be consistent about what you want and what is actually shown.

Comment: sorry about that. i have edited my post and changed the sample image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i knew it. i know that there is something missing with my condition..

```
if ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== ''){
            $criteria->compare('start_date', $search_date_start, false, '>=');
            $criteria->compare('end_date', $search_date_end, false, '<=');
        }
```

with this condition, only the start_date and end_date is validated. that is why it will only return the two dates. from and to.

this is what i did. this validates everything.

```
if ($search_date_end == '' && $search_date_start !== '') {
            $criteria->condition = "start_date >= '$search_date_start'";
        } elseif ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start == '') {
            $criteria->condition = "end_date <= '$search_date_end'";
        } elseif ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== '') {
            $criteria->condition = "start_date  >= '$search_date_start' AND end_date <= '$search_date_end'";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You add **3** conditions with start_date to your model's search method:

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('start_date', $search_date_start);
$criteria->compare('start_date', $this->start_date, true);
$criteria->compare('start_date', $search_date_start, false, '>=');
```

Imagine that your sql after WHERE looks like:

```
WHERE
    start_date='2015-10-01'
    AND start_date LIKE '%2015-10-01%'
    AND start_date>='2015-10-01'
```

the last two conditions become useless. So you need left only one condition.

P.S. Activate a trace log in main.php to look your SQL queries for debug:

```
'routes' => array(
    array(
        'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
        'logFile' => 'application_trace.log',
        'levels' => 'trace',
        'rotateByCopy' => true,
        'enabled' => true,
    )
)
```

Comment: Im not familiar with yii though. i dont know how to activate a trace log.. can you please walk me through it..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== ''){

    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('DATE_FORMAT(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d")',
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime($search_date_start)), 
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime($search_date_end)), 'AND');


    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('DATE_FORMAT(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d")',
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime($search_date_start)),
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime($search_date_end)), 'AND');
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it did not work. instead of returning 3, it returns nothing. i tried using $criteria->addBetweenCondition('start_date',$this->search_start_date, $this->search_end_date); but still returns wrong.